# Laravel - Issues with storing dynamic options in database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I have a select menu where users can select specific features, and depending on what they chose, a new select menu shows up with the new options. This process can be repeated several times depending on what they select.

For instance, if a select menu shows these items: `apple, mango, orange.`

And the user selects `apple`: They will get three additional options that are related to the apple – `brown, red, green.` If the user selects `orange` for example, they may see `red, orange.` Notice that red shows up twice.

My main issue is having a good way of tracking it down.

#### My current solution

I have two tables - `features` and `feature_group.`

`feature_group` has columns: `id`, `name`
`features` has columns: `id`, `group_id`, `name`, `links`

If we go back to the previous example,

I'm currently storing the options in the `links` section.

**`feature_group`** table:

```
| id | name   |
|----|--------|
| 1  | Fruit  |
| 2  | Colour |
| 3  | Taste  |
```

**`features`** table:

```
| id | group_id | name   | links     |
|----|----------|--------|-----------|
| 1  | 1        | Apple  |           |
| 2  | 1        | Mango  |           |
| 3  | 1        | Orange |           |
| 4  | 2        | Red    | 1,2,3     |
| 5  | 2        | Green  | 1,2       |
| 6  | 2        | Orange | 3         |
| 7  | 3        | Slicy  | 1,2;1,2,3 |
| 8  | 3        | Okay   | 1,2,3,4   |
| 9  | 3        | Bad    | 2,4       |
```

As you can see, the `links` column contains the `id` of the `features` in the **same** table. So For instance, the 4th row, with name `Red` is visible when the user chooses any of the options `Apple, Mango, Orange.`

Similarly, if they cannot choose `Bad` as the third option if they have selected anything other than `Mango` for the first option and `Red` for the second option.

The `;` is used to include other option pairs as well.

I hope it makes sense.

This is my table structure. In code, I'm doing it as an array:

```
$color = [
    'Apple'  => [
        'Red',
        'Green',
    ],
    'Mange'  => [
        'Red',
        'Green',
    ],
    'Orange' => [
        'Red',
        'Orange',
    ],
];

$taste = [
    'Red' => [
        'Slicy'
    ],
    // so on...
];
```

I don't think this is the best way to do it. Especially if I want to add more things later on, then I have to modify my data a lot which can be troublesome.

How can this problem be fixed?

Comment: That seems to be a many to many self relation that could be handled at database level, but could you explain further how the `;` works in your context? What do you mean by option pairs?

Comment: `;` separates the values. For example, in the 7th row above, `1,2;1,2,3` would mean that the third option `Slicy` would only be visible if the user selects `1` and `2` from the first two select fields or if they select `1`, `2` and `3`. Anything else they select is not visible.

Comment: Why don't you put everything in his own table? `fruits`, `colours` and `tastes`. Then the pivots `colour_fruit` and `colour_fruit_taste`.

Comment: @azeós because that's not very efficient in the case that I want to dynamically create more features like `fruits`, `colours` and such.

Comment: Seems like the `links` column has two meanings. In line 4, the comma separated values is a list of all possible parents. On line 9, the comma list defines availability if a certain option sequence was chosen. Did I understand correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to have the freedom to go as deep as possible the following solution could work:

```
Table: features

| id | name  |
|----|-------|
| 1  | Apple |
| 2  | Red   |
| 3  | Green |
| 4  | Sweet |
| 5  | Sour  |
| 6  | Cake  |
| 7  | Cider |

Table: feature_parent_child // maybe you have a better name

| parent_id | child_id |
|-----------|----------|
| 1         | 2        |
| 1         | 3        |
| 2         | 4        |
| 3         | 5        |
| 4         | 6        |
| 5         | 7        |
```

If we follow our relationships we can end up with:

```
Apple -> Red -> Sweet -> Cake -> ...
Apple -> Green -> Sour -> Cider -> ...
```

This way we can go as deep as we want. Also we can features that are child of other features to be "root" features:

```
Cake -> Sugar -> Sweet -> Apple
Cider -> Party -> Happy -> Cake -> Birthday
```

Difficulty is managing the amount of features.

*Update after comment*

Because of the infinite amount of level depth, it would be not smart to load all options at once. Therefor we are forced to load the next features by doing separate requests.

As first we can return all children of a given feature:

1. User selects first feature `id 1`.
2. API call is being made and returns all children of `id 1`, response `[2, 3]`.
3. Fill a new select input.
4. User selects second feature `id 2`.
5. API call is being made and returns all children of `id 2`, response `[4]`.
6. ...

I think, and please excuse me if I am mistaking, it is also possible to give each feature different children depening on its preceding parents. However this requires a little more logic.

Example:

```
Apple -> Red
Apple -> Green

Red -> Apple -> Tasty
Red -> Apple -> Cake
```

We can see that `Apple` has two child features `Red` and `Green`. However as soon as we have `Red` as a parent we can see that `Apple` has two different features, `Tasty` and `Cake`. The following procedure needs to be executed.

1. User selects first feature `Red`.
2. Get all features that have `Red` as parent. Which is `Apple` in the given example.
3. User selects `Apple`.
4. Get all that have `Apple` as parent and `Apple` has `Red` as parent. Which are `Tast` and `Cake`.

Comment: What do you mean by `features that are child of other features to be "root" features`?

Comment: "root" features as the feature where everything starts with its own child features.